# Can't Download Burp's CA Certificate from http://burp

Tags: certificates, burp-suite

I was trying to download burp's CA certificate for Firefox on Kali from http://burp as specified in its documentation but the site is not available. It redirects me to http://www.inert.com/. So is there any alternative to download the certificate?

Comment: Are your requests already going through the proxy when visiting `http://burp`?

Comment: Before you can access that URL, you must [configure your browser to work with Burp](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783055-configuring-your-browser-to-work-with-burp)

Comment: @PortSwigger yes I tried with and without configuring, but still things don't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are your options:

- http://burp - it failed for you for some reason
- http://localhost:8080/ - or your burp proxy address and port
- Proxy > Options > Import / Export CA Certificate > Export in your preferred format and append the correct file extension

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ works.

Comment: @ChandanGauns probably you are in a network with inproper dns records that redirects an "false" domain name to a specific web page ... just try to connect to something random